# \n new line escape sequence in ERB

Tags: ruby, escaping, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb, line-breaks

I'm not sure why "\n\n" is not adding two line breaks in my code below:

```
<%= (getparagraph(@geography, "geography")+"\n\n") if @geography != "Other" %>
```

To clarify the method getparagraphs simply returns a paragraph of text.  I'm trying to add two line breaks within the Ruby code without having to use `<br/>`

Any ideas? Everything I've read implies that it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your helper has "paragraph" in its name so maybe you should wrap it in a paragraph and use CSS to add the appropriate spacing around the paragraph:

```
<% if @geography != "Other" %>
    <p>
      <%= getparagraph(@geography, "geography") %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

You could always add a special class to the `<p>` if you need an extra spacing after this:

```
<% if @geography != "Other" %>
    <p class="geo-chunk">
      <%= getparagraph(@geography, "geography") %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

and then in your CSS:

```
.geo-chunk {
    margin-bottom: 2em; /* Or whatever works */
}
```

And if this is to appear inside another `<p>` then you'd need to re-arrange the HTML a bit as you can't put a block element inside a `<p>`:

```
<div>
    <!-- The old <p> content ... -->
    <% if @geography != "Other" %>
        <div class="geo-chunk">
          <%= getparagraph(@geography, "geography") %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks!  I went with option 1.  Of course, I didn't think to place the <p> or <br> tag between the if and end statements.

Comment: @Edward: Cool, I had to tweak option 2 a bit BTW, I remember that you can't (legally) put any block elements inside a `<p>` but that doesn't have anything to do with option 1.

Answer (score 4):

You're outputting HTML; whitespace is largely ignored upon rendering.

Use `<br/>` tags instead, and `.html_safe`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this within HTML? If so, then just use `<br>`. HTML ignores multiple whitespace characters, so you could have one space or 50 newlines and the result would be the same.

Another note: unless you're using XHTML (itself not a great idea), *do not* use self-closing tags such as `<br/>`. The slash is invalid, so omit it.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking, the slash is valid, but semantically different from what you might expect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201870/are-self-closing-input-tags-valid-in-html-4 .