# What is the difference between "<!DOCTYPE ...." and "<!DOCTYPE>" in a html document?

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have this HTML document that started with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

and contained a

```
<link href="https://somewhe.re/path/to/file.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

The content of the linked CSS file didn't seem to have any effect on the rendering of the HTML document, however. But when I downloaded the CSS file and referenced it locally (that is with a `href="../css/file.css"`), it worked as expected.

That was frustrating at best and I tried everything I could imagine to solve the "problem", but I couldn't reference the file on the server via HTTPS. Yet, when I changed the `<!DOCTYPE...>` to a simple `<!DOCTYPE>` it worked. I didn't expect that. Although it works now, I'd still like to know what's going on here.

**Edit**: The CSS' URL is `https://raw.github.com/golovko/Fixed-Header-Table/master/css/defaultTheme.css`.

Comment: If you revealed the real URL, maybe someone can solve your mystery. It is generally easier to solve a problem when the problem can be observed.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE>` is not a valid SGML or HTML5 DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: @BoltClock Where did you read html5?

Comment: @René Nyffenegger: Can you post your html code?

Comment: @SK11 Here's the html: https://gist.github.com/2051528

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I would suspect the problem has to do with the self-closing `<link>`.  That's valid XHTML, but not so much HTML4.  This SO post has some good detail: [Are self-closing input tags valid in HTML 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201870/are-self-closing-input-tags-valid-in-html-4)

Try removing the slash at the end of the link tag and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try putting ../path/file.css instead of the full path.  Maybe there is a spelling error?  Self closing link tags are accepted in HTML 4 by the way.