# Does <img alt="foo" /> equal to <img alt="foo"></img>?

Tags: xml, tags

I'm curious, does XML standard allow me to write tags without content as one tag?

I'll give you 2 examples:

Can I interchange `<img alt="foo" />`  with `<img alt="foo"></img>` ?
Or can I interchange the tag implying and empty message `<message></message>` with just a simple `<message />` tag?

In the answer could you please quote the spec or show the source?

Comment: You have tagged with `html` and `xhtml`. These are conflicting tags. Pick one. Anyway, `<x></x>` and `<x/>` "should" be treated the same in XML (and thus XHTML), but it's possible for a particular XML consumer to do otherwise .. however, HTML is *not* XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are talking about XML or XHTML, then [the two forms are equivalent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags). In both [HTML4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201870/are-self-closing-input-tags-valid-in-html-4) and [HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) however, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do that. As long as the XML is valid you can do that.