# How do I end HTML 'meta' tags?

Tags: html, meta

How do I close HTML `meta` tags?

Is it like `<meta description="" />` or `<meta description="" >`, or are both right?

Comment: XHTML is dead. Just use `>`. (Or follow SO's example and use both randomly in the same page...)

Comment: Depends on HTML version, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201870/are-self-closing-input-tags-valid-in-html-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about XHTML syntax, do it with `<meta/>`. If not, you are free to use `<meta>` or `<meta/>`

Comment: If this helps you then it'll be appreciated to accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Need to wait 3 minutes :)

Comment: In HTML 4.01, for example, `<meta .../>` is invalid (browsers digest it, but markup validators complain).